# Webpack 4 replace import

Tags: webpack, import, require, commonjs

I have javascript file with `import`, for example

```
import React from 'react';
```

My webpack 4 config have

```
...
target: 'node',
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: false,
          babelrc: false,
          presets: [
            ['env', { modules: false }],
            'react'
          ],
          plugins: ['transform-object-rest-spread', 'transform-es2015-modules-commonjs'],
        },
      },
    },
    ...
```

Now my output javascript have all code from `react` library and size 63 Kb. But I no need this extra code. I want to see something like that only

```
'use strict';
var _react = require('react');
var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);
function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
```

Is there any way to get this?

Comment: Search for splitChunks on webpack 4.

Comment: @MatheusSilva, thanks for the advice, however this is not what I need. I just need to replace all `import` to `require`

Comment: Changing the target to node maybe help, also don't forget to add modules: false to babel config (env preset config, to be more specific), so webpack takes care of that for you, not babel

Comment: @MatheusSilva, thanks, it's a little bit helps. I've updated my post. Now I have `require`, however React's code still imported

Comment: Ok, just to understand the goal. Why do you need react to just have a require statement?

Comment: And btw, it is : `presets: [
            ['env', { modules: false }],
            'react'
          ]`. The target has to be done on the webpack config. Look here: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx

Comment: @MatheusSilva, my goal is use ES5 code with SSR